# Which version of PHP for Windows CLI based use?

Tags: php, curl, windows-server-2003

I need to run some PHP scripts from the command line on a Windows 2003 server. The server has Apache/Tomcat installed on it, but NOT PHP. The server is running a custom commercial web application and I don't want to touch the Apache/Tomcat configuration on it. We are looking to setup some schedule PHP cURL tasks that we'd run from the Windows task scheduler. Can someone point me to the right download for this?

Comment: The PHP executables don't magically install themselves into Apache.  In other words, just download the newest PHP windows executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PHP Freaks Forums:

> For just CLI purposes I'd go with a VC9 build that is non-thread-safe
>   of whatever the most recent version of php is (5.4.3 atm).
>
> There is no need for thread safety in CLI since each instance is it's
>   own separate process, and VC9 is a more recent compiler.  As far as
>   cURL goes all you should need to do is load the extension dll via the
>   php.ini file settings.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP downloads page](http://php.net/downloads.php)

Don't forget to add PHP to the system path.

Comment: If you don't need some unmaintained special module from some obscure website, go with the latest (VC9, thread-safe).